# SVN checksum mismatch while migrating repository

Tags: svn, checksum

after migrating our SVN repository from VisualSVN (Windows Server, SVN 1.7.7) to CentOS7 (SVN 1.7.14) we repeatingly (and each time for different files) get checksum errors when checking out from Eclipse or TortoiseSVN (Command line and GUI, all on Windows 7) from the new repository.

We already tried SVN 1.9.3 with re'dump'ing and re'load'ing via svnadmin, but it still fails with the same Checksum mismatch message. Its a show stopper for migration since we are unable to get the svn correctly installed. The error we get is:

```
checkout http://a.b.c.d/svn/xy/trunk -r HEAD --depth=infinity --force

svn: Checksum mismatch for 'C:\Free\dev\workspace\maven.1535642555604\XY'\xyz.java':
   expected:  77db5c9d4feff3f7c69e9e84e3eaad94
     actual:  07fc691c7225f05a70ffadb1450afdfd
```

We have direct internet connection, without proxy.

I googled around for two days now but found an solution. Can anybody help?

Thank you so much.
Best regards, Peter

Comment: Any chance you are using encrypted drive? BitLocker maybe?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But no, I don't use encryption. See also my answer to myself below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think found the problem. It's likely that the anti-virus software from our company caused these problems because checking out on another PC with a different anti-virus software works well.

Irritating for me was the fact that the SVNKit 1.8.12 SVN connector in Eclipse Neon did all checkouts always without failing, whereas JavaHL1.9.3 in Eclipse Neon, TortoiseSVN as well as its SVN command line client failed. I suspect that SVNKit ignores the system proxy settings, whereas all other clients don't do that. Further interesting is that switching the network settings in Eclipse between direct and native internet connection did not make any difference - SVNKit continues to work well, whereas the others continue to fail.

Although I obviously found the error cause I really wonder that anti-virus software can have impact on file checksums while svn checkout...

Peter